# \medskip doesn't seem to work

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

I've just begun using TeXShop but seem to have come across a problem - I have a centered section that uses a \medskip right after a newline. Like so:

```
\begin{center}
Some text \\
Some subheading \#1\\
More subheading \#3\\
\medskip
Last subheading\\
\end{center}
```

Which works fine. But when I do this in a paragraph, or item, or, for that matter, anything else. It seems not to work. `\medskip` inserts line spaces in unexpected places, and never after the newline that directly precedes the `\medskip`. I've also tried not using the newline to precede the `\medskip` at all, to no avail.

Your help is much appreciated, as usual!

-L

Comment: ``\\`` should not be used in normal text to mark the end of a paragraph. Leave a blank line; a `\medskip` is better preceded and followed by a blank line. In `center` it doesn't matter if it is or not.

Comment: if you want to leave more vertical space, you may use `\\[<space>]` as in `\\[12pt]`.

Answer (score 9):

You should hardly ever need to use explicit spaces in a latex document, spaces should be under the control of structural commands such as lists and section headings.

However `\medskip` is short for `\vspace{\medskipamount}` and use of `\vspace` in horizontal mode has a slightly odd effect that the space comes after the current line. This is almost always not what you want so `\vspace` if it is used at all is best used with a blank line before it, to get into vertical mode, so the space comes between paragraphs.

`\\` in the `center` environment is redefined so that it does `\par` internally but in most other cases you are not in vertical mode after `\\`. Perhaps you are looking for `\\[\medskipamount]`

Comment: Hey David, thanks. Would it be good practice then, to always use the blank line when I want space inbetween things? For example, if I want to make sure lines of a equation block are separated, I should use blank lines inbetween the source code?

Comment: @LukeChang Don't think in terms of the visual appearance so much as the meaning: you want a blank line where you want a new paragraph. Don't put a blank line before `equation` ever, TeX display math is not designed to start a paragraph and will insert an anomalous white empty paragraph if started in that position.  The amount of space before displayed equations is a class level parameter `\abovedisplayskip` and `\abovedisplayshortskip` which you can set in the preamble if you need to change it.

Comment: Plain TeX defines `\medskip` as `\vskip\medskipamount`, so there is no this potential reason of user confusions because `\vskip` primitive finalizes current paragraph when it occurs in the horizontal mode.